# Dynamic image loading.

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In a Image tag src = path, I want to dynamically load the image by pulling the image name from the database. How can I do that?

```
<img src="../../Content/themes/base/images/pepsi.jpg" height="100" />
```

I want to be able to write this some thing like this

```
<img src="../../Content/themes/base/images/" + model.item.name + """ height="100"/>
```

I am using MVC3 razor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
      <img src="../../Content/themes/base/images/@model.item.name" height="100"/>
```

If not,

```
      <img src="../../Content/themes/base/images/@(model.item.name)" height="100"/>
```